# What does getBackgroundPage() function return exactly? (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm currently trying to return the FIRST* image displayed on a webpage with code:

> img.src = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().imageSrc[0]

0 represents the first image. This seems to work. However, the getBackgroundPage() is only functional with the tab currently opened. I want this to work even if the user is using a different webpage.

In discovering how to find the first image of a website that ISn't currently runnning, I first have to understand what chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() returns. Is it a string? Or a url?

I've tried replacing this with,
[document.getelementId("hi").getsrc.]imageSRC[0]...hi is represented in htm as as a div with src of a url that I want...But it does not work. Any solutions?

Comment: is there a reason your not simply using `$("img").first().attr("src")`?

Comment: @Nikerym may not have jQuery.

Comment: Nikerym because I can't find that for the specific page. How would I edit that code for the first image of a page that isn't open?

Comment: @Christian  He used the Jquery tag... kinda assume therefore a jquery answer would be acceptable.

Comment: @Nikerym where? The first and only instance of '$' is in your comment. Something camel cased doesn't mean jQuery....

Comment: sorry if confusing. no jquery

Comment: @Christian Down the bottom,  where it says "javascript"  "jquery"  "html" "css"  "google-chrome" as the tags for the post.

Comment: Aha, thanks for clarification @Nikerym, I missed the tags and read the code. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to use an extension to do this?

Try this;

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

This is vanilla javascript and needs no plugins, extensions or particular browsers.

**EDIT**

To answer your question;

> Returns the JavaScript 'window' object for the background page running inside the current extension. Returns null if the extension has no background page.

Thats according to [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage).

**EDIT 2**

Ok, so, chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() returns the 'window' object, which means you may be able to do this;

```
w = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
w.document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

**EDIT 3**

Once you have a dom object, you can get any attributes like so;

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
```

**EDIT 4**

Apologies for not understanding initially. Have a look at the source for the 'BitBucket Notifier' extension on chrome. [Most importantly this file](https://bitbucket.org/koddsson/bitbucket-notifier/src/66d8d3e57a6fa5d02d4ee4d491127b0b565c75e5/main.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

It polls Bitbucket every 5 seconds (if I'm reading it correctly) and returns data from the site for the extension.

Could this be used in your extension?

Comment: I'm making an extension that provides updates of a specific site with pictures. In the code you provided, do I need to set the document as the url I'm trying to reach?

Comment: No, document is a global variable, it can be used as is. Try running it in your console to see what it returns.

Comment: I have but I only need one webpage's results :/ not global results sir.

Comment: Oh, I see, you may not have a page focused, is that right?

Comment: @SenEmilien see my 2nd suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have the results for the page i'm on. I need results for an unopened page, that will show even when it isn't open. I'm trying to show image updates. If the user has to click open the site, they may as well not download the update extension. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yep. Did you try my 2nd suggestion?

Comment: It seems like your answers are providing me with code that performs the same function as the one I originally listed. I'm trying to perform something different. Instead of a background page, I want the variable to be a url.

Comment: Ok, so you want the URL of the first image? The source? Or, do you want the URL of the page/window? 
I have added code for retrieving the src. Apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: I wanted the code for retrieving the src of a specified url*. You didnt misunderstand. I suppose I didn't explain properly. everyone seems to be confused on the question. maybe the answer doesn't exist? i want it to show me the first img src of youtube.com and youtube.com only.possible?

Comment: But, is youtube.com open when it gets the image?

Comment: no. unless it's open in a background page that the user can't see? :D

Comment: Ok, I understand (finally!) See my update in my answer.

Comment: ok...I think I'm closer. still not sure how to declare the dom object as youtube though. Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes, although im trying to do this in popup form, this isn't your puzzle to figure out. you've guided me far enough. thanks Christian.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90200/discussion-between-sen-emilien-and-christian).